# How can I start a file-processing daemon?

Tags: shell-script, files, monitoring, startup, daemon

How can I run a script-based tool which will process files continuously downloaded to given directory as they arrive? I'd like to minimize delay (~1 second is OK), script can have own infinite loop.

I know a few ways, like:

- autologin user with `.bashrc` or `.profile` calling my script
- fork script from cron, then ignore if it is already running
- use init scripts somehow (I guess it varies between distributions)

What method would work best?

Comment: Exactly, what are you trying to accomplish? And why isn't a resident download manager a good option?

Comment: Another process download files, which have to be processed, output pushed, original file deleted. Rinse and repeat. Design should be reboot-resistant.

Comment: On Linux, use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en). It's a program whose job is precisely to run a specified program when files are created or modified.

Run the command `incrontab` to edit your rules. A rule may look like this:

    /incoming-directory IN_CLOSE_WRITE process-file-command --option $@/$#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your script is to run under Linux, you can use [inotifywait](http://techarena51.com/index.php/inotify-tools-example/) from an init script. You will probably want a recursive search through the entire download tree (option `-r`). Bear in mind that each node to watch [can eat up to 1kB of kernel memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535768/what-is-a-reasonable-amount-of-inotify-watches-with-linux#7091897).

The main advantage of *inotify* is to prevent a costly polling loop. It triggers an event as soon as a file operation takes place in the watched directory tree and consumes non-noticeable CPU resources otherwise.

Answer (score 12):

> use init scripts somehow (I guess it varies between distributions)

It does indeed.  Here's the systemd way, which doesn't involve System 5 `rc` scripts at all.  It's two units.  Because they are non-package non-system units they go in `/etc/systemd/system`.  The first is a *service unit* that describes running your program as a dæmon:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/example-spooler.service

[Unit]
Description=Process files in /var/spool/example/
Documentation=http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203637/

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/example-spooler /var/spool/example/
```

Note that you don't have to explicitly start or stop this service.  It is *path activated*.  The *path unit* that describes the path that systemd monitors and what it looks for is the second unit file:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/example-spooler.path

[Unit]
Description=Watch /var/spool/example/ and activate example-spooler.service
Documentation=http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203637/

[Path]
DirectoryNotEmpty=/var/spool/example/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To auto-start this at bootstrap, run `systemctl preset example-spooler.path`.  To start it now, run `systemctl start example-spooler.path`.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemd.path`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.